# Count positive elements in list

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme

Im trying count the number of positive elements in a list.  Here is what I have so far:

```
 (define howMany
   (lambda (list)
      (cond
         [(not (list? list)) 0]
         [(null? list) 0]
         [(> list 0) (+ 1 (howMany (cdr list)))])))
```

It keeps giving me an error, "expects type real number", how would you fix this?

Oh im calling this like so:

```
(howMany '(6 7 8))
```

Comment: Surely, you mean Scheme and not Schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of bugs in your code.

`(> list 0)` should be `(> (car list) 0)` as you want to check if the *first element* of the list is greater than 0. You cannot apply the default implementation of `>` to a list either.

`(+ 1 (howMany (cdr list)))` will also fail as `howMany` does not always evaluate to a number. You have to maintain a counter by passing that as an argument to the recursively called procedure. One way to do this is:

```
(define (howmany lst)
  (let loop ((n 0) (lst lst))
    (if (null? lst) n
      (loop (if (> (car lst) 0) (add1 n) n) (cdr lst)))))
```

Test:

```
> (howmany '(1 2 3 4 5))
5
> (howmany '(1 2 3 -4 5))
4
> (howmany '(1 -2 3 -4 5))
3
> (howmany '(-1 -2 3 -4 5))
2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't expect `(> list 0)` to work — `list` is a list, but `>` expects its arguments to be numbers.

You want to see if the *first* element of the list is positive, so that should be `(> (car list) 0)`.

However: there's a bigger problem with your code: what happens if the first element is negative or zero?

Comment: Do you mean `#t` and not just `t`?

Comment: Yes, `#t`. I'm more of a lisper than a schemer, and I often forget about these small differences.

Comment: I see your point, if the first number is zero or negative it doesnt do anything.  If the list looks like this: '(1 2 -3) it crashes and tells me expecting type number.

Comment: That's because if none of the cases match, the value of the `cond` expression "returns unspecified values" (as it says in [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.4.5))—probably in fact it returns `#f` or `()`. And then you try to add 1 to this, which is a type error since `+` expects its arguments to be numbers.

Comment: Expect `cond` to return `<void>` or other suitable nothing if none of the clauses match.  `'()` actually counts as true.

Comment: GNU/MIT Scheme certainly follows the spec closely: `(cond (#f)) ==> ;Unspecified return value`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: `(> list 0)`

You're comparing a list to a number. Try `(> (length list) 0)` or `(not (null? list))`. Or whatever the Scheme keyword for "default condition in a `cond` block" is.

Edit: This is what you get when you focus on error messages foremost. Gareth has it right, of course.

Comment: Scheme has no special keyword for "default condition in a cond". You just give `#t` (scheme's keyword for true) as the condition when you want a default condition.

Comment: Ahh thanks. I dabbled in Common Lisp a bit, so Scheme looks like a foreign dialect to me.

Comment: "no special keyword" — there's `else` in [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.4.5)

Comment: I think the `else` clause of Scheme has been around a lot longer than R6RS.

Answer (score 0):

```
positiveCounter(seq)
  if typeof(first(seq)) == num
      if first(seq) > 0
          return positiveCounter(rest(seq) + 1
      else
          return positiveCounter(rest(seq)
  else
      #Handle Errors Somehow.
```

Pseudocode for the recursive algorithm I would use.

I don't know either Scheme or Clojure (which your square brackets remind me of).

Or you could write a considerably snazzier applicative approach in Common Lisp- extra newlines for readability.

```
(defun positiveCounter (seq)
  (reduce #'+
          (mapcar
           #'(lambda (x)
               (if (atom x)
                   (if (> x 0) 1 0)
                   0))
           seq)))
```

Comment: The square brackets that some Schemes allow are purely for readability — they're the same thing as parens. The Scheme equivalent is pretty close: `(define (positive-counter seq) (apply + (map (lambda (x) (if (number? x) (if (> x 0) 1 0) 0)) seq)))`

Comment: @Chuck: `(if (and (number? x) (> x 0)) 1 0)`, surely?